# Rest API Thread Safety

Tags: java, multithreading, rest, api, thread-safety

I was wondering how should I design a Restful API so I can guarantee it will be Thread-Safe, how should I manage the resources and how should I handle mutual exclusion?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restful API is just an additional layer built on top on  old good Servlets API. So, you can just check common topics about Servlets and thread safety.